# What is the name of the panel that holds the tabs?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to change the background color of the panel that has the tabs, but I don't know its name.

I tried:

```
        "[Material Theme Darker]": {
            "editor.background": "#14161B",
            "activityBar.background": "#14161B",
            "sideBar.background": "#111114",
            "sideBarSectionHeader.background": "#161618",
            "activityBar.border": "#14161B",
            "tab.activeBackground": "#14161B",
            "tab.inactiveBackground": "#19191d",
            "editor.selectionBackground": "#27292e",
            "editor.inactiveSelectionBackground": "#303236",
            "statusBar.background": "#14161B",
            "tab.inactiveForeground": "#757575"
        }
```

I need to change the color of this panel: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsW7q.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for the

`"editorGroupHeader.tabsBackground"`